# How do I store a record once and reference it many times in other tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord, normalization

I have a table of ingredients.  When a user inputs an ingredient, it saves in the table.  Now what I'm noticing is that many records repeat, and I don't want that, what I want is for each of these records to be referenced if it already exists.

So for example, I have flour saved about 20 times in the DB.  I want it to be saved once, and for each recipe, when a user inputs flour, it should just reference that ingredient in the DB.  How do I achieve this?

I already have an Entry model (recipe), and a join EntryIngredient model.  So whenever an Entry saves an Ingredient that already exists, I want it to just reference that one in the EntryIngredient table (as foreign key) instead of create a new one.

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entry_ingredients
  has_many :entries, :through => :entry_ingredients

end

class EntryIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry
  belongs_to :ingredient

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

end

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :entry_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :entry_ingredients
  has_many :steps

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :entry_ingredients, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps, :reject_if => lambda { |s| s[:description].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Dynamic finders sound like they do what I want, specifically `find_or_create` or `first_or_create` but I'm not able to figure out how to use them in my setup.  Can anyone push me in the right direction here?  This is what I've tried but I realize that this is just creating a new ingredient whenever the entries#new is called... not what I want to happen

```
  #entries_controller.rb
  def new
    @entry = Entry.new
    @entry.entry_ingredients.build.build_ingredient
    @entry.steps.build

    @ingredient = Ingredient.where(params[:ingredient]).first_or_create()

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @entry }
    end
  end

#_entry_ingredient_fields.html.erb
<%= f.fields_for :ingredient do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.label :name %>
  <%= builder.text_field :name, :class => "ingredient_field" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: look at an autocomplete solution when adding ingredients. also add a uniqueness validation to the name of the ingredients to at least prevent duplication based on names.

Comment: but if i add uniqueness validation a user would get an error when saving an ingredient that already exists...  maybe I'm supposed to be using has one instead of has many?  I'm gonna post my models now.

Comment: with an autocomplete solution in place, you don't have to worry about failing the uniqueness validation.  it's just there so you won't have duplicates in the db.  if it's already existing in the db, then the autocomplete feature should be used.  If not, then a free form text field can be added which will create a new ingredient.

Comment: I do not want to use autocomplete yet, gems do magic and I'm still learning.  I want to figure out how to link records, can anyone show me how to do that with or without dynamic finders??

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know exactly what you need without seeing some code, but if I understand correctly, you want to create an ingredient only if it doesn't exist yet.

Check out rails' [dynamic finders](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders). If you use a method name like

```
@ingredient = Ingredient.find_or_create_by_name("flour")
```

it will create a new object if there was no entry with the name "flour" before or return an existing ingredient called "flour". In both cases, @ingredient will hold the desired entry returned by the statement above. Rails will create it for you only if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: so how do i use that with data from the view?  Users will be passing in the argument, params[:name]?

Comment: That's right. Just pass in whatever you need as the ingredient name. Check your params hash to get the exact key, but it will be something like `params[:name]` or rather `params[:ingredient][:name]`.

Comment: Sorry I've been trying to get it to work but haven't been able to.  I may just be doing it wrong, I've put in my Ingredient model `@name = self.name`, `@ingredient = self.find_or_create_by_name(@name)` and in my view I changed the form field to `f.text_field :ingredient_name` I'm clearly doing something wrong going to take another stab at it right now, let me know if you have any suggestions.  When I put params[:name] in the arguement I was getting an error undefined local variable or method params

Comment: Can I have a look at your repo?

Comment: sure thing, its github.com/technomad/baking_journal

Comment: I don't see the `find_or_create`
 method
 in any controller. In which controller and method have you tried it?

Comment: This is something you would typically use inside the controller. If I understood correctly, when creating or updating you want to either create or reference the according ingredient. Since your entry accepts nested attributes for ingredients, it's a bit tricky - but you would need to do something like this pseudocode: `if the entry's ingredient name already exists, find that record and assign it to @entry.ingredient, if not just leave it inside the params`. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: Yup thats exactly what I'm trying to do, I'll let you know when I get it working, but I tried putting it in the model because if its in the controller I'd need to put it in the new and edit actions, I figure I could define a method for it and then try to access it in the text field helper... i'm very new to rails so this is all conjecture and I'll let you know what happens in the end, thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, please let me know :) I wish you success!

Comment: I'm still not able to get this to work, can you look at my updated code and give me a hint?